# Setting a class property at run time in c# crashes Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

In working on a larger wp7 project, I kept coming across this issue:

Any time I set a property in my code, it crashes Visual Studio 2010.
So I decided to do a proper test to try to isolate the problem.
The following code is a short wp7 app example that has the same issue in the same way.  Whenever the code tries to set the name property, it crashes Visual Studio.

Notes:  I have no add-ins installed, and when I try to run this in safe mode, I get the error "The Project Type is not supported by this installation"

Any help would be appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace propertytest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public string name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                //crash!
                if (value != name)
                {
                    name = value;
                    hi(name); 
                }
            }
        }
        void hi(string name)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi "+name);
        }
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
            DataContext = App.ViewModel;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
            name = "your name";
        }

        // Load data for the ViewModel Items
        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Call Stack:**

```
propertytest.dll!propertytest.MainPage.name.set(string value) Line 14   C#
propertytest.dll!propertytest.MainPage.MainPage() Line 34 + 0xb bytes   C#
     mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo rtci, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr,     System.Reflection.Binder binder, object parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool isBinderDefault, System.Reflection.Assembly caller, bool verifyAccess, ref     System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)    
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x114 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.InternalCreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0xf0 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type) + 0x2 bytes  
Microsoft.Phone.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(System.AsyncCallback userCallback, System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result) + 0xe6 bytes   
Microsoft.Phone.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad.AnonymousMethod__0(object args) + 0x11 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool isBinderDefault, System.Reflection.Assembly caller, bool verifyAccess, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)   
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x168 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object obj, object[] parameters) + 0xa bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(object[] args) + 0x98 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) + 0x8 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(object[] args) + 0x2 bytes   
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() + 0xc bytes    
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority) + 0x83 bytes  
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(object context) + 0x8 bytes 
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(object[] args) + 0x19 bytes 
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(object[] args) + 0x2 bytes 
System.Windows.RuntimeHost.dll!System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(System.IntPtr pHandle, int nParamCount, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam[] pParams, ref System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam pResult) + 0x5e bytes 
[External Code] 



**Debug Output:**
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'mscorlib.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Windows.RuntimeHost.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Windows.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Net.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Core.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Xml.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\1782A5A4-3D00-47D3-A109-B889805E61F9\Install\propertytest.dll', Symbols loaded.
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'Microsoft.Phone.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\1782A5A4-3D00-47D3-A109-B889805E61F9\Install\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll'
```

Comment: +1 purely for posting a question that is a stack overflow on stack overflow.

Answer (score 8):

You're calling the setter recursively:

```
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value; // <-- Argh! Recursion!
                hi(name); 
            }
        }
```

If you want to implement the getter/setter that way, you'll need to use a private member variable:

```
       private string _name;
       public string name
       {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    hi(_name); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: One way to recognize these situations is by sticking tot the MS naming conventions. In this case the property would have been called Name and that might have been more obvious.

Comment: I think he is calling the getter recursively first as if check will recursively call the getter and it will never get to the line you indicate, which would indeed cause a recursive loop as well.

Comment: Btw, i would recommend using String.Compare() for string comparison.

Answer (score 4):

You have an infinite recursive loop

This bit

`if (value != name)` calls the getter of the property

e.g. this bit

`get { return name; }` which in turn calls itself until you blow the stack.

You need to use a backing field to store value in a backing field;

```
private string _name

 public string name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                // won't crash any more
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    hi(name); 
                }
            }
        }
```